# Server Click event is not firing after client click event return true in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, excel

I am creating a website and use a popup for exporting grid data to excel sheet 
but I have trouble 
I have created a javascript method and call it on client click of asp.net 
here is my function

```
<script>
    function change() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Store/ViewStock.aspx/CountStock",
            data: "{'fromDate':'" + $('#<%= txtFromDate.ClientID%>').val() + "', 'ToDate':'" + $('#<%= txtToDate.ClientID%>').val() + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d != null)
                    var count = data.d[0].Count;
                if (count > 0) {
                    $('#emptyDataRow').hide();
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    $('#emptyDataRow').show();
                    return false;
                }
            },
        });
    }

</script>
```

And

Here is my button

Close

I have used `OnClientClick="return (!change()){ return false;}"` but its server click not working when its true 
Help me how to tackle this issue?? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax is an asynchronous function. So those return calls wont work.

Why are you concerned with the return of the `change` function?
You can just do:

```
onclientclick="change()"
```

Also as a side note, I think it's better to define your variables outside of an if statement, so they are not undefined downstream:

```
var count = 0;
if (data.d != null)
  count = data.d[0].Count;
if (count > 0) {
  $('#emptyDataRow').hide();
}
else {
  $('#emptyDataRow').show();
}
```

Comment: But i want to disable the server click if this function returns false
it should work exactly like return confirm() works onclientclick of any button

Comment: I think one way you can go about doing to is to `preventDefault` in your handler function.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: I think the easiest way to achieve what you are trying to do is to call whatever it is that you are about to do on the server-side before returning the ajax call. So in the viewstock.aspx/countstock endpoint, before you return the result, do whatever is appropriate based on the count.
Another approach could be to make another ajax call to the server based on the result of the first ajax call.